# Showing WLAN selection dialog with Symbian Qt

Tags: qt, symbian

I'd like to offer the user a dialog with a list of available wlan access points when the default access point doesn't work. According to the `QNetworkConfiguration` reference, when a configuration's type is `UserChoice`, `QNetworkSession::open` would popup a dialog for choosing a configuration. But my experience is on N8 (with Symbian Anna) is that

- every wifi access point I ever used is shown up as a part of the "Internet" destination in Connectivity > Settings > Destinations,
- which results in having only a single configuration in `QNetworkConfigurationManager::allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Discovered)`, which has the name "Internet" and type `ServiceNetwork`

So is it possible to change connectivity settings in N8 to get a configuration with `UserChoice` type, and will it solve my problem?

What's the proper way to make possible that the user can connect to a new wlan access point from a Qt/QML application without going to Settings?